# Angular error NG8002, error TS2341 (Problem with the html and ts files)

Tags: html, angular, typescript, error-handling, git-bash

I have been trying to find the error for 2 hours. Anything seems fine, and it works before i add the [(NgModule)]="toDo$.label". It is also declared at the template-todo-form.component.ts as:

This is the html file -> template-todo-form.component.html

```html
<div class="todo-form">
    <div class="todo-content">
        <input type="text" [(NgModel)]="toDo$.label" placeholder="Was muss erledigt werden?">
    </div>
    <div class="create">
        <span>Erstellen</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the Typescript abstract:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ToDo } from '../../_interface/todo';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-template-todo-form',
  templateUrl: './template-todo-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./template-todo-form.component.sass']
})

export class TemplateTodoFormComponent implements OnInit {

    
    private toDo$: ToDo;
    constructor() {
        this.toDo$ = {
            label: undefined,
            status: false
        };
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    // Create new ToDo
}
```

For your interest -> im working with the gitbash, so i copy&paste the error output.

```
$ ng serve
- Generating browser application bundles...
ÔêÜ Browser application bundle generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files   | Names         |    Size
main.js               | main          | 0 bytes
polyfills.js          | polyfills     | 0 bytes
runtime.js            | runtime       | 0 bytes
styles.css, styles.js | styles        | 0 bytes
vendor.js             | vendor        | 0 bytes

| Initial Total | 0 bytes

Build at: 2021-03-23T18:10:05.416Z - Hash: 5b02fccf2cebb89bf415 - Time: 8328ms

Error: _template/template-todo-form/template-todo-form.component.html:3:28 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'NgModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.

3         <input type="text" [(NgModel)]="toDo$.label" placeholder="Was muss erledigt werden?">
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  _template/template-todo-form/template-todo-form.component.ts:6:16
    6   templateUrl: './template-todo-form.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component TemplateTodoFormComponent.


Error: _template/template-todo-form/template-todo-form.component.html:3:41 - error TS2341: Property 'toDo$' is private and only accessible within class 'TemplateTodoFormComponent'.

3         <input type="text" [(NgModel)]="toDo$.label" placeholder="Was muss erledigt werden?">
                                          ~~~~~

  _template/template-todo-form/template-todo-form.component.ts:6:16
    6   templateUrl: './template-todo-form.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component TemplateTodoFormComponent.


Error: _template/template-todo-form/template-todo-form.component.html:3:41 - error TS2341: Property 'toDo$' is private and only accessible within class 'TemplateTodoFormComponent'.

3         <input type="text" [(NgModel)]="toDo$.label" placeholder="Was muss erledigt werden?">
                                          ~~~~~

  _template/template-todo-form/template-todo-form.component.ts:6:16
    6   templateUrl: './template-todo-form.component.html',
    m                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component TemplateTodoFormComponent.




** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **



I Hope the information is useful to help me asap... 
Thanks at the front :-)
```

Comment: its `[(ngModel)]`, note the lowercase *n*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its lowercase 'n' that you need to use.

`[(ngModel)]` binds the value that you tie it to. So your HTML should look like this:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="toDo$.label" placeholder="Was muss erledigt werden?">
```

Comment: Im asking myself why am i so blind :D the NG8002 Error is gone, but the two TS2341 Error are already existing. You got some solution for that too? Thank you btw.

Comment: Haha it happens. I understand. Can i ask why you defined the todo$ as a private variable? any particular reason? If you remove private and use it, you may not see the issue. 

Private variables are not preferrred in components. They are preferred in service files. 

Because they want to access that variable only when that service is initiated within a component using Dependency Injection (DI). 

If there's a particular reason, please tell me and i might be able to help but in general you need not do privatization of variables.